# How do I collapse rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

I have two dataframes. df.A has two columns, one with road names and one with page numbers and grids (ie. 10 A4). df.B will be the results df and it has two columns, one with the unique road names and an empty one for page numbers. df.A contains duplicate roads as they cross multiple grids.(see below).

```
11  ACCESS RAMP    18-C4
12  ACCESS RAMP    13-D2
13  ACCESS RAMP    11-A1
14  ACCESS RAMP    11-A4
```

How do I consolidate this data in a new dataframe, or in the same one, so that there is one row like:

Access Ramp    18 C4, 13 D2, 11 A1, 11 A4

df.B has 1564 entries. df.A has 3130

I have tried a loop in a loop and several other variations but I think I am missing something with indexing perhaps. I have had results where all 3000 values are stored in each of the 1500 rows and results where only one value is applied to the df.B page column but it goes down the index and one by one enters them instead of aggregating them.

```
for st in f_t['street']:
    LV = ''
    for i in df['st_label']:
        if (i==st):
            LV = LV + ', ' + df[GridName']
    f_t['Grids'] = LV
```

This one ran down the indexes but then also duplicated the value. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you just trying to collapse the rows with the same road name in dfA to produce the new row? You're not trying to merge in anything from df.B, right? If so, I've added an answer in below which I believe may work for you if the answers to my questions are both "yes" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're after?

First let's load up some nonsense data into dfA:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'road': ['ACCESS RAMP', 'ACCESS RAMP', 'ACCESS RAMP', 'ACCESS RAMP','ACCESS DRIVE', 'ACCESS DRIVE', 'ACCESS DRIVE', 'ACCESS DRIVE'],
    'grid': ['18-C4', '13-D2', '11-A1', '11-A4','19-A4', '11-D1', '9-Z1', '19-D6']
}

dfA = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Next, let's group the information in the dataframe by the roads column using the groupby function, and join all the associated values in the grid column (separated by a comma in this case).

```
result_df = dfA.groupby('road')['grid'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

result_df looks like this:

| road | grid |
| --- | --- |
| ACCESS DRIVE | 19-A4, 11-D1, 9-Z1, 19-D6 |
| ACCESS RAMP | 18-C4, 13-D2, 11-A1, 11-A4 |

Comment: So basically, instead of looping through two dataframes and trying to match values, you're kinda just collapsing the data based on common values in the "road" column and storing that in the new dataframe.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure if I have tried groupby() or not but this is exactly what i was looking for. I'll add this to my notes for the future. Thanks a lot!